# The %SourceFileName% macro can only be used with the http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2006/sftp-properties namespace

Tags: c#, .net, biztalk, biztalk-2013, custom-pipeline-component

**Overview**

I have a custom send port pipeline component that replaces the file name of the file being mapped on the send pipeline with a specific file mask format.  The pipelines code takes the ReceivedFileName property and applies transformation to it.  This process has been working for over a year, but after deploying a new schema and maps resource, the pipeline has ceased to work.  I now get no file created due to the below warnings and errors.  I am hoping that someone may have had a similar experience and could give me insight into this issue.

Notes: The maps and schemas work (new and old) when not using the pipeline. The only change to the maps and schema artifacts were an addition of 2 TypedPolling schemas, 2 FlatFile schemas, and 2 maps.

**Here is the Warning and Error I got using the SFTP adapter**

Warning

> The adapter failed to transmit message going to send port
>   "SEND_FileFormat_BSFTP" with URL
>   "SFTP://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:22/ToPartner/sftp/%SourceFileName%". It will
>   be retransmitted after the retry interval specified for this Send
>   Port. Details:"An unexpected failure occurred while processing a
>   message. The text associated with the exception is
>   "[SftpTransmitterEndpoint] Unable to transmit file . Inner Exception:
>
> The %SourceFileName% macro can only be used with the
>   http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2006/sftp-properties namespace. .
>   Changing any Send Port Transport properties might require the host to
>   be restarted, as the connection pool might still have connections".".

Error

> A message sent to adapter "SFTP" on send port
>   "SEND_FileFormat_BSFTP" with URI
>   "SFTP://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:22/ToPartner/sftp/%SourceFileName%" is
>   suspended.   Error details: System.ArgumentException: A property with
>   the name
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/file-properties#ReceivedFileName'
>   is not present.
>
> Server stack trace:     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageProperties.get_Item(String name)
>   at
>   Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Sftp.SftpOutputChannel.BuildFileName(Message
>   message)    at
>   Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Sftp.SftpOutputChannel.Send(Message message,
>   TimeSpan timeOut)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr
>   md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage
>   msg, IMessageSink replySink)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(SendAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action,
>   Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndSend(IAsyncResult
>   result)
>
> Exception rethrown at [1]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.IOutputChannel.EndSend(IAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfClient`2.SendCallback(IAsyncResult
>   result)   MessageId:  {055A8864-AB06-4849-ADC3-A5CB93016106} 
>   InstanceID: {FF1E3802-89CD-466C-B68E-2CF4EC662DF4}

**Here is the error I got using the Blogical SFTP adapter**

> Method:
>   Blogical.Shared.Adapters.Sftp.SftpTransmitterEndpoint.ProcessMessage
>   Error: [SftpTransmitterEndpoint] Unable to transmit file . Inner
>   Exception: The %SourceFileName% macro can only be used with the
>   http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2006/sftp-properties namespace. .
>   Changing any Send Port Transport properties might require the host to
>   be restarted, as the connection pool might still have connections
>
> ------------------------------ Information: Type: Blogical.Shared.Adapters.Sftp.SftpException Target:
>   Microsoft.BizTalk.Message.Interop.IBaseMessage
>   ProcessMessageInternal(Microsoft.BizTalk.Message.Interop.IBaseMessage,
>   Blogical.Shared.Adapters.Sftp.ISftp) Message:
>   [SftpTransmitterEndpoint] Unable to transmit file . Inner Exception:
>   The %SourceFileName% macro can only be used with the
>   http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2006/sftp-properties namespace. .
>   Changing any Send Port Transport properties might require the host to
>   be restarted, as the connection pool might still have connections
>   Stacktrace:    at
>   Blogical.Shared.Adapters.Sftp.SftpTransmitterEndpoint.ProcessMessageInternal(IBaseMessage
>   message, ISftp sftp)    at
>   Blogical.Shared.Adapters.Sftp.SftpTransmitterEndpoint.ProcessMessage(IBaseMessage
>   message)
>
> ------------------------------ Type: System.Exception Target: System.String
>   ReplaceMacros(Microsoft.BizTalk.Message.Interop.IBaseMessage,
>   System.String) Message: The %SourceFileName% macro can only be used
>   with the http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2006/sftp-properties
>   namespace. Stacktrace:    at
>   Blogical.Shared.Adapters.Sftp.SftpTransmitProperties.ReplaceMacros(IBaseMessage
>   message, String uri)    at
>   Blogical.Shared.Adapters.Sftp.SftpTransmitterEndpoint.ProcessMessageInternal(IBaseMessage
>   message, ISftp sftp)

I have tried:

- Refreshing the pipeline, schema, and map artifacts
- Using %MessageId%, %SourceFileName%, and *.dat as my SFTP filename values
- Stopping the send ports, restarting the host instances
- Stopping everything in the app and restarting all host instances
- Re-gaccing the artifacts
- Using a File adapter instead of SFTP

Comment: When your message suspended with error from your sftp send port. have you verified the  ReceivedFileName property do exists in your message context and its namespace is 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/file-properties'

Comment: It does not exist.  The pipeline will inject those properties into the message context within the SEND Pipeline of the send port.  The send pipeline in the past would replace %SourceFileName% with our transformed ReceivedFileName.

Comment: Based on your desciption "The pipelines code takes the ReceivedFileName property and applies transformation to it. ". The ReceivedFileName property should exist in message context no matter if your send pipeline component executed or not.   I think now you need check why this property missing in your message,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved by completely redeploying the pipeline assemblies.  The DLLs got out of sync as they were published. The GAC versions did not match the versions deployed to BizTalk.

Comment: Yes, having different versions of the DLL deployed in BizTalk and the GAC will cause some weird errors.  Always import it into BizTalk and Install into the GAC.